# CombSort implementation in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am using Comb Sort to sort out a given array of Strings. The code is :-

```
public static int combSort(String[] input_array) {
        int gap = input_array.length;
        double shrink = 1.3;
        int numbOfComparisons = 0;
        boolean swapped=true;
        //while(!swapped && gap>1){
        System.out.println();
        while(!(swapped && gap==1)){
            gap = (int)(gap/shrink);
            if(gap<1){
                gap=1;
            }
            int i = 0;
            swapped = false;
            String temp = "";

            while((i+gap) < input_array.length){
                numbOfComparisons++;
                if(Compare(input_array[i], input_array[i+gap]) == 1){
                    temp = input_array[i];
                    input_array[i] = input_array[i+gap];
                    input_array[i+gap] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                    System.out.println("gap: " + gap + " i: " + i);
                    ArrayUtilities.printArray(input_array);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        ArrayUtilities.printArray(input_array);
        return numbOfComparisons;        
    }
```

The problem is that while it sorts many arrays , it gets stuck in an infinite loop for some arrays, particularly small arrays. Compare(input_array[i], input_array[i+gap]) is a small method that returns 1 if s1>s2, returns -1 if s1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this version. The `string` array is changed to `integer` array (I guess you can change it back to `string` version). The constant `1.3` is replaced with `1.247330950103979`.

```
public class CombSort
{
    private static final int PROBLEM_SIZE = 5;
    static int[] in = new int[PROBLEM_SIZE];

    public static void printArr()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<in.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(in[i] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void combSort()
    {
        int swap, i, gap=PROBLEM_SIZE;
        boolean swapped = false;
        printArr();
        while ((gap > 1) || swapped) 
        {
            if (gap > 1) 
            {
                gap = (int)( gap / 1.247330950103979);
            }

            swapped = false;

            for (i = 0; gap + i < PROBLEM_SIZE; ++i) 
            {
                if (in[i] - in[i + gap] > 0) 
                {
                    swap = in[i];
                    in[i] = in[i + gap];
                    in[i + gap] = swap;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
        printArr();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<in.length;i++)
        {
            in[i] = (int) (Math.random()*PROBLEM_SIZE);
        }
        combSort(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below implementation for comb sort in java.

```
public static void combSort(int[] elements) {

    float shrinkFactor = 1.3f;
    int postion = (int) (elements.length/shrinkFactor);
    do {
        int cursor = postion;
        for(int i=0;cursor<elements.length;i++,cursor++) {

            if(elements[i]>elements[cursor]) {
                int temp = elements[cursor];
                elements[cursor] = elements[i];
                elements[i] = temp;                 
            }
        }
        postion = (int) (postion/shrinkFactor);
    }while(postion>=1);
}

Please review and let me know your's feedback.
```